# XML response on REST API

Tags: php, xml, api

## edit

how to add a encoding in the xml "header"

now the "header" looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

how can you when using SimpleXML in PHP add a encoding in the "header"?

my xml class:

```
class XML {
    private $root = '<response />';
    
    function __construct($root=null){
        $this->root = new SimpleXMLElement($root ? $root:$this->root);
    }
    
    function encode($arr, $node=null){
        $node = $node == null ? $this->root:$node;
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $this->encode($value, $node->addChild($key));
            }
            else{
                $node->addChild($key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    function output(){
        return $this->root->asXML();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well my Danish isn't perfect (or present at all for that matter). However, I know as a fact XML nodes [cannot begin with a number](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html). And since the error seems to be complaining abou the well-formedness of the XML data, I'd say it's because of the `<0></0>` node.

You can try to change:

```
private $root = '<response />';
```

To something like this:

```
private $root = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><response />';
```

Comment: ok.. im new to xml.. has always used json.. but how can you write an array in XML then? just put a name before the array sequence/index?

Comment: The equivalent of an "array" in XML is literally a group of nested sibling elements with the same node name.

Comment: but then what about the special chars as æøå? how to handle them in xml? could you just add a charset in the xml doc or the header?

Comment: Yep, using something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` should help you out.

Comment: do you know how to add the encoding using simpleXML in php? have edited my question